# Get date of last time a module in Excel was changed / imported

Tags: excel, vba, module

I was curious if there is a way to get the last update date or import date of an Excel module. Like imported/created 25.06.2019, last time updated 01.07.2019.

I have a folder with all my ClassModules, Modules, Forms and want to Update all Excel files which uses one of them to update to the latest version if its older than 7 days. The only possible solution so far I could imagine is to write the update / current date to a header in the module etc. file and read it before importing.

Greetings and thanks for any information on this

Comment: I have a folder that has all the latest versions of modules, forms and add-ins. I then have them loaded in at start as I know that anything in this folder will always be the latest version. Reduces the need for checking for latest version

Comment: thats a other possible solution for the problem. Thats why I was curious if it is even possible to look for such information

Answer (score 0):

This will give you that last save time/ last modified time. You can call it from a cell, ie. `=LastModified()`

See below:

```vb
Function LastModified() As Date

   LastModified = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

End Function
```

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for. I do not need the last Save time of the Workbook. I would like to know the last import/create/edit date of a specific module in VBA of my active Workbook